# How to add a pop up using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html code:

```
<form id="room-from" method="post">
<input id="room" type="text" name="room" />
<input type="submit" id="save" name="save" />
</form>
```

when i press the save button if the room text field is empty a pop up should appear at the center of the screen and must say enter a room number.

jquery:

```
    $("#save").submit(function(){
    if ( $("#room").val() == "")
{

}
    });
```

I'm not sure how to do this.

Can anyone please help me out on this.

Comment: Have you made any research? Tried to google?

Comment: You'll want to do a search for `modal`, the term used for what your describing. There are an insane amount of plugins, etc available. The twitter bootstrap ones are quite nice, but like I said, there are many available options. Take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use modal window and jQuery UI it will make your life easy

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Thanks but I have used the jquery-mobile popups.

Comment: nice one did't know it existed. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: cancel submission added.

```
   $("#save").submit(function(event){
        if ( $("#room").val() == "")
        {
                alert("enter a room number");
                event.preventDefault();
        }
   });
```

Comment: Can also check for `!$("#room").val()`

Comment: And cancel The submission perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#save").submit(function(){
    if ( $("#room").val() == "") {
        $("#site_blackout").fadeIn(200);
        $("#popup_modal").fadeIn(400);
    }
});
```

Then just use CSS to center the popup_modal and style the site_blackout.

Comment: And cancel the submission perhaps?

Comment: Thanks but I have used the jquery-mobile popups.